Next.js(App Router), Laravelで開発時のAPI通信戦略
認証：tymon-jwtauthで生成したjwtをAuth.jsで管理しています。
案１：コンポーネント→tRPC→Route Handler(sessionからトークン取得しヘッダーに詰める。ログ管理もここ)→laravelAPI

メリット→セキュア、laravel-dataで型定義ファイル吐き出してそれをRouteHandlerで使うことでまあまあ型安全
デメリット→複雑

案2:コンポーネント→tRPC→laravelAPI

メリット→簡潔　工期短縮
デメリット→JWT管理に気を使う　　ログなどの管理が散らばる

状況：転職と技術的な興味のための個人開発　堅くかきたい気分
その他にもいい案があればご教示いただきたいです。
